# ScrollTo method not woking in react native ScrollView component

Tags: react-native, scrollview, scrollto

`scrollTo()` is not working in react native - `ScrollView` Component

I am trying to scroll to top of screen on tap of button which is in the bottom of the screen. Screen is scrollable and lots of contents and other component inside `ScrollView` Component.

**Function to scroll to top**

```
_scrollToTop = () => {
      this.sv.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, Animated: true})
}
```

**Component inside render to call _scrollToTop function**

```
<ScrollView ref={c => (this.sv = c)}>
.
.
.
.
   <Button onPress={this._scrollToTop}>
     <Icon name="arrow-up" } />
   </Button>

</ScrollView>
```

But when button is tapped, nothing happens.

### Using following environment:

"react": "16.8.6",

"react-native": "0.60.5",

Comment: Please try `onPress={() => this._scrollToTop()}`

Comment: @schogges already tried. Doesn't work.

Comment: Do you get any error logs? or warnings. Also does your scrollview do something in onScroll?

Comment: @NemiShah no any errors or warnings.  But I used scrollToPosition(), and its working

Comment: Ah well react native is a little volatile and sometimes things that are supposed to work just don't. Can you edit your question to provide the solution? It will help others who face the problem

Comment: Try `this.sv.current.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, Animated: true})`